Central Limit Theorem for Array of Dependent Random Variables
I am wondering if there is a central limit theorem for array of dependent random variables. Suppose we have array of random variables $\{X_{nm},n=1,2,\dots,m=1,2,\dots,r_n\}$ where $X_{nm}$ are identically distributed, within each array $X_{nm}$ are dependent but independent across arrays (i.e., $\{X_{11},\dots, X_{1r_1}\}$ and $\{X_{21},\dots, X_{2r_2}\}$ are independent and so on). Any reference in this connection is greatly appreciated.

See e.g. https://alexandersokol.dk/VidSand1/lecture13.pdf

@vanderWolf Thank you. But, in this case, the variables in each array are $dependent$.

If you assume Lindeberg's condition, then they will converge in distribution.

It is important to specify what kinds of dependence you wish to allow. There are many basic dependence structures between a family of random variables, such as stationarity, weak stationarity, mixing conditions, Markov or martingale conditions.  If you make no assumptions on how the variables are related to each other it is hopeless to say anything.

@tsnao Could you please suggest reference(s) that covers all these kinds of dependence structures?
